# Will c++ ctre regex have much performance instead of c# usual regex?

Tags: c#, c++, pinvoke, cross-language

I have an application written by C#. I need to process a big text file. For each string, I need to parse 3-10 alphanumeric values and recalculate them. Regex is perfectly suitable for that. But c# regex is not fast enough.
I tried to use [ctre (compile-time regular expressions)](https://github.com/hanickadot/compile-time-regular-expressions) library by Hana Dusikova (C++ 17) and it had a perfect performance.
I need to call regex for line by line reading.
If I use PInvoke calling from C++ library how much spent it Will be?
I want to make a  c++ library and do calls from C# when I need to parse the line.
Is it a good idea?

Comment: Have you tried to use [RegexOptions.Compiled](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.regularexpressions.regexoptions?view=netframework-4.8)? Not sure if that will have a big performance impact tho.

Comment: And, are you compiling the c# code to a binary?

Comment: Why don't you write a sample program in C++, measure the time it takes and compare to the C# program?

Comment: @Longoon12000 of course. When I use ctre regex it takes near 9 seconds for 220MB file and c# regex takes near 35 seconds. It is 388% - a very fine result.

Comment: note that the RegexOptions.Compiled that I linked is c# regex, not an external library like the ctre that you linked

Comment: @luxun In a simple test ctre regex has a fine result. But I didn't use PInvoke (call c++ code through c# application), that test is expensive because program objects have a difficult structure. For full testing, I need a lot of time. To write that code is not easy.

Comment: @Longoon12000 with RegexOptions.Compiled it was faster. Increased by 10% in real-life testing... Not so much.

Comment: For me, any decision around a P/Invoke based tool needs to incorporate marshalling time. I've had transit costs eat up more than a 388% performance boost because the interface was too fine grained.

Comment: @parktomatomi I found the best solution. It's a precompiled regex by C#.
I took a test file with a size 220MB. I tried to compare interpreted, compiled and precompiled regex by C# and I got these results: 1)Precompiled regex: 18453 ms; 2)
Compiled regex: 18713 ms; 3) Interpreted regex: 25928 ms.